# What percentage of HIV cases are caused by each of the following pathways?

Tags: infectious-diseases, hiv

Most studies of STI focuses on sexual intercourses.  For example one study shows that approximately [70% of HIV is caused by male-male intercourse](https://www.webmd.com/hiv-aids/hiv-men-sex-men#:%7E:text=About%2070%25%20of%20the%20estimated,made%20up%2069%25%20of%20those.), and 20% is caused by heterosexual sexes.

However, I cannot find reliable data of the percentage of each of the possible pathways. For a list:

1. injection of addictive drugs
2. injection of drugs or blood for **medical** reasons
3. Sexual intercourse
4. non-penetrative sexual conducts (such as kissing)
5. Mother-child transmission
6. etc.

How do I find the data for the approximate percentage of cases that are caused by each the reasons above?

Note: the percentage data is calculated by the number of cases of one cause divided by the total cases. It can be an estimation, but it is different from the [risk per exposure](https://www.cdc.gov/hiv/pdf/risk/estimates/cdc-hiv-risk-behaviors.pdf)

Comment: It'll strongly depend on where you are in the world and which publications you are looking at as a consequence.

Comment: World data is the best but any data from the major countries (like G8, G20) would help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a start, from [WHO/European Centre for Disease Control](https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/publications-data/hivaids-surveillance-europe-2020-2019-data). From the report, for new infections in Europe not including the Russian Federation (or Belgium) in 2019:

- 50% heterosexual contact (not subdivided by penetrative/non-penetrative contact, but the latter will be a tiny fraction)
- 21% sex between men (ditto)
- 13% injecting drug use
- 0.7% mother-to-child transmission
- 0.2% "other" (nosocomial, transfusion or use of other blood products)
- UNKNOWN 15%

See [Table 8 in the full report](https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/hiv-surveillance-report-2020.pdf) for a country-by-country breakdown.

**Note**: these numbers (which are reported on p. 38 of the full report) are for the "WHO European Region", which includes lots of eastern European/former Soviet (including Central Asian) countries, where **reporting** (not necessarily actually infections!) is heavily skewed to heterosexual transmission (10 to 1). The figure below is for EU/EEA countries only.

[image]

Comment: Great to see an answer to this difficult question, so kudos! How does this answer square with the EU/EEA average pie chart puting sex between men at ~50% with heterosexual sex trailing by 6-7(?)%. I haven't read anything but the conclusion, but am curious from where your breakdown is obtained and if it's accurate. Is it based on sheer numbers? Is the pie chart not based on numbers?

Comment: I'm just quoting values from page 28 of the report. I didn't try to match up numbers between the report and the figure ... Conceivably the pie chart made a mistake in the legend/colour assignment?? Seems unlikely.  With more time, could look at Table 8 and see how the various country-level pie charts match up with the table ...

Comment: (Table 8 lists 9525 from sex between men, 8164 from heterosex, 955 from drug users, 167 from IVDU, so maybe I misunderstood the numbers on p. 28 ???)

Comment: @BenBolker I'm not finding the numbers you mention on page 28.

Comment: Oops, p. 38 ...

Comment: oops, discrepancies may be between "EU/EEA" and "WHO Western Region"

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yeah, that does seem to be the case.

Comment: There it is. Thanks!

Comment: Yes EU $\neq$ Europe